# remove all python packages no matter how they were installed

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

So at work I have been given an AWS instance, not of my own making, where apparently several different python packages were installed my different means. Every time I use pip I get

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1
```

I can install packages using easy_install but the server uses Jython and it's not picking up the new packages,  etc.. etc.. etc..

The company is supposed to use pip,  so I want to remove every package and start fresh as it were.

Mr google says there is no easy way to do this,  but I also cannot find ANY way to do this.  If I just delete every file in my package directory,  do a yum --uninstall pip  --  and then start fresh,  will that work?  Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: Could you spin up a fresh AWS instance and start again?

Comment: The people at large want that to be the last ditch effort.  It's may be the way we go,  but I at least need to try.

Comment: How about installing a fresh copy of Python?  Maybe there's a new version out.  If you use that, you'll be starting from scratch.  You might also be able to use a VirtualEnv, which I know does not bring across all of the packages from the base Python install, but I don't know if it gives you a virgin environment regardless of how the underlying Python environment has been manipulated.  I would feel more comfortable ignoring or deleting the existing version completely rather than messing with the packages directory.

Comment: I have to use 2.7 for Jython.

Comment: Can you delete the existing 2.7 and start over that way?

Comment: Can I?  will that remove all the packages with it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will. - this is why you can have a bunch of Python versions on your machine, and they all play nice together.  They each keep their packages very close to the vest, so to speak.

Comment: If you only deleted the packages directory, I'd be worried you'd lose some of your base Python install, although just removing the 'site_packages' subdirectory might do it.  But if you remove all of Python, you won't have to worry about that, since the reinstall will set up a clean environment with all the base packages in the right place.

Comment: Hey...and I bet you could just rename your existing Python install.  It should all be in a single directory.  Then you wouldn't have to do anything irreversible, at least until you knew the new version was working. - That's the key.  From my experience, everything about a particular Python version is contained in that versions's root directory and below. - If you find anything outside of the Python directory, I bet it's a sym link, like `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191692/discussion-between-steve-and-mmaceachran).